# How do I embed the ItemTemplate for a wpf ListBox into the Window's resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemtemplate

Sorry if this is a basic question, but how can I take an ItemTemplate that I have for a ListBox, and put it in the resources for the window so that more than one ListBox can use it.

Here's some XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Example">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="dtExample">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            // styles go here...
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dtExample}">
    // items go here...
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

This is throwing a "Attached property has no setter" design-time error.  I've removed portions of code that I didn't think would matter, for sake of brevity.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just add your itemtemplate to your window's resource and add a key:

```
<Window.Resource>
 <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
  ....
 </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

and then apply it with something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}">
 ...
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I tried putting my ListBox.ItemTemplate xaml inside of a DataTemplate, but get the red squiggly error, Attached Property has no setter.  Ideas?

Comment: well, the ItemTemplate property of an ItemsControl IS a datatemplate. if you provide some code/markup it would be much easier to help you. just stating you get an error won't help ;)

Answer (score 2):

you provided the following code:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="dtExample">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        // styles go here...
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </DataTemplate>
```

but this will not work. you **cannot** provide `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>` directly within your template. you don't need this here. just create a simple datatemplate and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the post is too old to be interesting for the author, yet i may be interesting for those who have the same problem and google it. As I may see the problem is you should use ListBox.ItemTemplate inside ListBox. For instance, `<ListBox ...><ListBox.ItemTemplate> ... </ListBox.ItemTemplate></ListBox>`

Comment: That was indeed my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you should x:Key properties in your resources instead of the x:Name..

Change that, and it will work like a charm :)

Comment: I changed it to a key, and that stopped the ItemTemplate from being greyed out in the xaml, but I still get the error:
The attachable property 'ItemTemplate' was not found in type 'ListBox'.

...and I have the ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}" in there, as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following tags in your Window class?

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

Comment: Hmm if it still does not work.. can you perhaps post your whole xaml file?

Comment: (Which is to say, yes, I do have those tags in my Window class).  :)

Comment: Yikes, I'd like to omit the parts which aren't causing the problem, and that I shouldn't share...I'll comment some things out and and try to duplicate the problem again...and edit in some 'sanitized' xaml here in a bit.  Clearly something funky is going on.

Answer (score 0):

the subject is old but here is the solution:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItem_Color" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            *//style*
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.resources>

<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox"
         ...
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItem_Color}">
      <.../>
</ListBox>
```