# How can I replace <ComboBox.ItemTemplate> with a style?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have many comboboxes that shows the same type of Enum. The Enum value is converted to text through a converter. The converter is added to each ComboBox inside a ComboBox.ItemTemplate. Like this:

```xaml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AnimalList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAnimal}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AnimalToTextConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

But I don't want to repeat the ComboBox.ItemTemplate for each ComboBox.

Can I replace the ComboBox.ItemTemplate with a style? How should I write it?

Comment: Or is it possible to replace the ComboBox.ItemTemplate with some sort of global conversion of all Enums of this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I replace the ComboBox.ItemTemplate with a style?

If you **really** want to solve this via styles, you can do that too of course:

```xaml
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="AnimalComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AnimalComboBoxItemTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

> Or is it possible to replace the ComboBox.ItemTemplate with some sort of global conversion of all Enums of this type?

You can just define your ItemTemplate for the entire window (or the entire application). Each ContentPresenter will be able to find it based on the DataType property.

```xaml
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type yourNamspace:YouType">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AnimalToTextConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
<Window.Resources>
```

This will not only work for ComboBoxes but every other ItemsControl, ContentPresenter, etc. too.

Answer (score -1):

```
<Window.Resource>
 <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
  ....
 </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}">
 ...
</ComboBox>
```

I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/641821/3729935).

You can also place the DataTemplate inside of the App.xaml Application.Resources-Tag:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp">
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
           ....
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

To reference it do the same as above.

To make it work with Enums place this in your ViewModel:

```
private MyEnum _selectedMyEnumValue;
public MyEnum SelectedMyEnumValue
{
    get { return _selectedMyEnumValue; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this._selectedMyEnumValue)
        {
            this._selectedMyEnumValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<MyEnum> _allMyEnumValues;

public IEnumerable<MyEnum> AllMyEnumValues
{
    get
    {
        if (this._allMyEnumValues == null)
        {
            this._allMyEnumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>();
        }

        return _allMyEnumValues;
    }
}
```

And the correlating XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllMyEnumValues}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMyEnumValue}" />
```

There's no need for a converter here.